# How to split columns into different lines

Tags: bash, extract, line

I have a txt file with multiple lines and 2 columns in each line, this is an example of a line:

```
SRR23337893.12582  CATTTGTAGCGCTACGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTAAGGGTTAAGCA
```

Anyway, I want to split the columns into different lines, the desired output is in this format:

```
SRR23337893.12582 

CATTTGTAGCGCTACGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTAAGGGTTAAGCA
```

I tried to use the tr command `tr "\t" "\n"` , but it didn't work for me, it just delete the second column !

Does anyone have an idea !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output of `xxd input` or a similar hexdump?

Comment: Try `sed 's/\s+/\n/g'`, i.e. convert all non-zero sequences of whitespace into a newline.

Comment: If awk is an option, perhaps `awk '{print $1; print $2}' file.txt > newfile.txt` will solve your problem?

Comment: Seems like you have windows line ending (CRLR) in the file. Try to use `dos2unix` or other means to convert the line endings.

Comment: assuming that's a single tab between the 2 fields, your `tr` works for me (ie, the data is split across 2 lines); my first guess would be that your file contains some odd/unexpected characters so the requested output from `xxd input_file_name` would help

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this with sed:

```
$ echo -e "SRR23337893.12582  \t CATTTGTAGCGCTACGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTAAGGGTTAAGCA" | sed 's/[ \t]\{1,\}/\n/'
SRR23337893.12582
CATTTGTAGCGCTACGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTAAGGGTTAAGCA
$
```

The sed command will replace the whitespace characters (space and tab) with a new line.
It assumes that your columns do not contain white spaces!